# Opening to one specific variable Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have a store displaying multiple items store in a service. When I click on a specific product, I need to go to another page to display the current item.

To clarify, I need to be able to click on an item displayed in the store view which opens to a new page using item view and displays the relative information of the item clicked. For example, clicking item 1 on store will open a page displaying information of item 1.

Currently, it opens to an empty page url of /item/:itemId rather than the actual item page. I was given help on this, the code is somewhat correct, but not working as intended.

I have two views, store and item. Store displays all of the items, where item would display the selected item from Store.

My code of current is:

**Store Controller**

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope, StoreService){
    $scope.items = StoreService.items();
  });
```

**Services Snippet (removed the multiple variables to save space, but there's 12 in total and all have their unique itemId).**

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .service("StoreService", function() {
    var items = [ {
      itemId: 1,
      qty: 0,
      stock: 5,
      price: 99.00,
      name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, Patent Black',
      category: 'Womens Footerwear'
    }];
    this.items = function() {
      return items;
    };
  });
```

**ItemCtrl**

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('itemCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, StoreService) {

    var item = null;
    var itemId = $routeParams.itemId || null;

    if(itemId){
      item = StoreService.getItemById(itemId);
    }

    $scope.items = StoreService.items();
  });
```

**Item Route**

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/item/:itemId', {
        templateUrl: 'app/item/itemView.html',
        controller: 'itemCtrl'
      })
  });
```

**ItemView**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div class="item-page-container">
  <div class="item-p-img">
    {{item.name}}

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**StoreView**

```
<!-- Item Container -->
  <div class="flex_container">
    <!-- Start of item iteration -->
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <!-- Start of item -->
          <div class="item">
            <div class="item_info">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Bn1iB6X.jpg"/>
              <div class="item_footer">
                <div class="info_text">
                  <h2>{{item.name| limitTo: 8}}...</h2>
                  <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <a href="/item/:itemId"><button role="button">More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- End of item -->
      </div>
    <!-- End of item iteration-->
  </div>
<!-- End of Item Container -->
```

Apologies for the long question, but truth be told, I can never get it working in Plunker. I'm still very much an angular beginner. If there's another method, I'm happy to try that.

Comment: Not clear what the problem is and the question.

Comment: What don't you understand so I can edit the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here;  you posted a series of code that all looks valid on the surface.  what is actually happening? is it going to the wrong page? Is it loading something else? is it loading nothing at all? is it throwing an error?

Comment: for that matter, where is the code for the `<button>` or `<a>` that goes to this route?

Comment: and where is the `StoreService.getItemById` function at?

Comment: @Claies I'm not completely wised up to this code, I've provided all the code I have.

Comment: then you don't have everything you need in order for this to work.  even if you reach the page you are trying to get to, it will error the moment it tries to call that function that doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay. How do I write this function? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't look correct, for starters.

```
<a href="/item/:itemId"><button role="button">More</button></a>
```

You want to pass the actual value in the href, and the route provider will translate this into the variable.  This would be the correct way to wire the two pages up:

```
<a ng-href="/item/{{item.itemId}}"><button role="button">More</button></a>
```

This will generate a url like `/item/1` or `/item/2` or whatever.  Note the use of angular `ng-href` instead of the plain HTML `href`.

Next, your controller is accepting `itemId` as a parameter, and attempting to make a call to `StoreService.getItemById(itemId);`, but that function `getItemById` doesn't exist in your service.

you would need something like this:

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .service("StoreService", function() {

    ... //other service code

    this.getItemById = function(itemId) {   
      var obj = this.items.filter(function (item) {
        return item.itemId === itemId;
      });
      //filter returns an array, and we just want the matching item
      return obj[0];
    }
  }
}
```

This function takes in the `itemId`, and then uses it to filter the `this.items` array into a temporary array called `obj`.  The filter returns every `item` which matches the `itemId`, which should in theory only be one `item`.  it then returns the first (only) item in the temporary array, `obj[0]`.  This code probably should be augmented with checks to ensure that `itemId` is valid, and that `obj` isn't empty after the filter, but it should get you started.

Also note that this code is for demonstration only, and was written to match your in memory implementation of `items`.  In a production application, you probably would have method calls which actually fetch data from a server.

Comment: Thank you for providing this! Okay, so I understand so far. So now, I need to write the logic to find a single item? 

That's where I'm stuck, I'm not proficient in Javascript, I'm learning more as I go.

Comment: well, since you *currently* have your items in an array, you just need to use an array function to search through the array to find the one that matches your Id.

Comment: Again, no idea how to do that. I'm having an issue understanding the logic, I just about have a grip on what's going on as it is.

Comment: well technically searching for an object inside an array is a question all by itself, and actually has multiple answers on the site already.  however, I'll try to write a quick sample for you.  that being said, the questions you have asked so far lead me to believe that you might want to study a bit more about how JavaScript works before digging deeper into angular; angular can have a steep learning curve for JavaScript experts....

Comment: Ah, yeah, thanks. 

Very true, I've had a tough time coming here, but I've understood each step, but all together, it can become slightly confusing. Is there some documentation for Javascript worth looking into or a book even?

Comment: I would probably try https://egghead.io/tags/free, or http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, though recommendations are discouraged because of the amount of spam they generate.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, you said that when you click on an item, it should go to a different page. I do not see an 'ng-click' in your view. Am I not understanding the question properly?

Comment: This should be a comment. Anyway, to answer, where would I place the ng-click?